# Combination of superscript and Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

Is it possible to use a superscript for a Unicode character?

For example, I have the expression `aaa=u'Intel\u00AE'` that creates the registered symbol as expected, but how could it be made a superscript?

Answer (score 4):

Unicode does not support making arbitrary characters into superscripts. There are pre-encoded [superscript characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts); they are different characters you can convert to.

If you want to make an arbitrary character a superscript you'll need to use markup or a typesetting system.

Comment: I found the solution shortly after posting the question. I was trying to use the registered and trademark symbols. For some reason, printing the strings returned one of the characters as a superscript but the other was printed standard font. However, matplotlib plotted both characters as superscripts (which solved my problem).