In Java, Is possible to print doubles like this: "¹" instead of "^1"?
I have two variables, two double vectors. I want to print with Unicode like this:
"1¹.¹¹¹¹"
(the exponent would be the double), but I don't know how do it exactly.
package Math;

import java.util.Scanner;

public Class Exponent() {

    double[][] num;
    double[][] Exp1;
    double[][] Exp2;

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    num = new double[3][3];
    Exp1 = new double[3][3];
    Exp2 = new double[3][3];

    for (int f = 0; f < num.length; f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < num.length; c++) {
            num[f][c] = key.nextDouble();
            Exp1[f][c] = key.nextDouble();
            Exp2[f][c] = key.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}

I have a method to convert the doubles to Unicode, but I'm not sure how to apply it to vectors. Obviously, I need a loop for the vectors, but I'm not sure where.
public static String DbltoUni(double[][] Exp1, double[][] Exp2) {
    char[] unicode = {'\u2070', '\u00B9', '\u00B2', '\u00B2', '\u2074',
        '\u2075', '\u2076', '\u2077', '\u2078', '\u2079'};

    String numStr1 = Double.toString(Exp1[][]);
    String numStr2 = Double.toString(Exp2[][]);
    StringBuilder Str = new StringBuilder();

    for (char digit : numberStr.toCharArray()) {
        double digitVal = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
        Str.append(unicode[digitVal]);
    }
    return Str.toString();
}

More or less, I understand the method, but I have to fix it for the double vectors.

You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616411/is-there-a-unicode-combiner-akin-to-a-superscript-style

Your DbltoUni() function converts a single Double, so it should take a single Double as input.
Also, your unicode array has '\u00B2' in it twice.  The 2nd one needs to be '\u00B3' instead.
Also, Character.getNumericValue() returns an int, not a double.
Try something more like this:
public static String DbltoUni(double value) {
    char[] unicode = {'\u2070', '\u00B9', '\u00B2', '\u00B3', '\u2074',
        '\u2075', '\u2076', '\u2077', '\u2078', '\u2079'};

    String numStr = Double.toString(value);
    StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();

    for (char ch : numStr.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            int digitVal = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
            if (digitVal >= 0 && digitVal <= 9) {
                bldr.append(unicode[digitVal]);
                continue;
            }
        }
        bldr.append(ch);
    }
    return bldr.toString();
}

Now, you can loop through your vectors converting each Double and using the output as needed, eg:
for (int f = 0; f < num.length; f++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < num.length; c++) {
        String str = DbltoUni(num[f][c]);
        ...
    }
}


Ok thanks, I'll see how to adapt it.
